# Como utilizar view's do MySQL com o Spring Data e eclipselink

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

No desenvolvimento do meu projeto me deparei com um select que vai exigir muito da performance da aplicação, pois consiste na utilização de dois join's. Logo me veio em mente a criação de uma view em MySQL, mas o problema é que nunca utilizei consumi a mesma com eclipselink e o Spring Data. Alguem já passou por isso? Não estava querendo realizar `@query("minha_consulta")` para trazer os dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@utluiz, ficou nota 10! Tive que fazer o seguinte, criei um view no meu BD:

```
select c.id_customer, c.tenant_id, c.first_name, ds.name 
from viatgedb.customer c
join viatgedb.customer_service cs
on c.id_customer = cs.fk_customer 
join viatgedb.destination_requested ds on cs.id_customer_service = ds.fk_customer_service;
```

Logo após fiz o mapeamento JPA (estou trabalhando com a arquitetura multi-tenant):

```
@ReadOnly
@Entity
@Table(name="vw_open_services")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "tenant_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty = PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
public class VwOpenService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_customer")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name="day_service")
    private String dayService;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    // Getter and Setter
```

E normalmente criei um repositorio para trazer meus registros com o Spring Data:

```
@Repository
public interface OpenServiceRepository extends BaseRepository<VwOpenService, Long>{

    List<VwOpenService> findAll(); 

}
```

O resultado foi o esperado.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

É possível mapear uma *view* como uma tabela comum usando `@Entity` e `@Table` sem dificuldades. Já fiz isso algumas vezes usando Hibernate.

Só atente para não usar geração de DDL, caso contrário o EclipseLink pode tentar executar um `ALTER TABLE` na *view*.

Além disso, não altere a entidade, isto é, quando você recuperar um objeto do banco, não use os métodos *setters* pois o JPA entende isso como uma alteração nos dados e tentará fazer um `UPDATE`.

Entretanto, especificamente no EclipseLink, acredito que os dois problemas acima podem ser evitados usando-se a anotação [`@ReadOnly`](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_readonly.htm) na sua entidade.

Exemplo:

```java
@ReadOnly 
@Entity 
@Table(name = "VW_MINHAVIEW") 
public class ReadOnlyEntity { ... }
```

Comment: Salve @utluiz! Estou lendo aqui sobre a criação da mesma. Vou tentar implementar, mas como fica isso junto ao Spring Data? eu realizo um select normal? No que pude entender acho que seria dessa forma.

Comment: @JoãoManolo Seria exatamente da mesma forma que uma entidade normal. Pode usar JPQL ou Criteria do mesmo jeito.

Comment: existe um problema em declarar a anotação `@Entity`. Ela me ped um `@id` até onde eu sei não faz muito sentido um view conter uma chave primaria. Como você tratou isso?

Comment: @JoãoManolo Sim, há essa limitação por parte da API do JPA. Deve ter algum campo na sua view que é único. Anote ele como `@Id` sem medo.